# How does Reddit sort query their database for "what's hot"?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, voting, reddit

I want to implement something similar on my site.

Submissions have up_votes and down_votes. I'd imagine reddit does some sort of database query that takes into account the up_votes vs. total_votes and maybe factors in # of views and # of comments and limits it all by a specified time period.

What sort of query do you imagine they use to determine this?

Thanks!

Comment: The best way is to just look over their [source code](http://code.reddit.com/).

Comment: @hammar - this is exactly what i was looking for.  submit it as an answer and i'll checkbox it.  thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- For links, they use a formula based on upvotes minus downvotes combined with age of the post.
- For comments, they use a confidence sort based on a [Wilson score interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval).

[This blog post](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588) describes both formulas in greater detail.